# Pointer of class to point on subclass (Polymorphism)

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

Suppose A is supercalss of B and C. 
B is a superclass of D and E, 
C is a superclass of F and G. 
(G and F extends C, E and D extends B, C and B extends A)

I have an array of type A and I want it to choose randomly (let's say 50/50 chance)
Between classes B or C, and B or C to point randomly on object of class D or E and F or G. 
So eventually I can perform functions on the array of type A (A will point on D, E, F or G)

Can I do it by creating an object (randomly) inside the contractor of B or C?

Comment: *Can I do it by creating an object (randomly) inside the contractor of B or C?*: what does that mean? What is a contractor? And... why don't you try to do it instead of asking if what you have in mind is correct?

Comment: Mistyped Constructer** and I did try it but my execution was wrong so I asked for advice... And if that's even possible.

Comment: Then post what you tried. Explain what you expect your code to do and what it does instead. A constructor of B creates a B. You can't put code in the constructor of B to make it construct something else.

Comment: just to emphasize: the constructor does not create an instance; the `new` statement creates the instance and then executes the constructor to initialize it - so `new B(...)` will always result in an instance of `B` (or an Exception) Seems like you need the Factory pattern or similar (e.g. `A.createRandomInstance()`) or work with delegates (`A` has an internal instance that will do the job)

Answer (score 0):

I think you trying to do something like this:

```
class A
{
    int value;

    A(int val)
    {
        value =val;
    }

    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println("value in A ="+value);
    }
}

class B extends A
{   
    B(int val)
    {
        super(val);     
    }

    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println("value in B = "+value);
    }
}

class C extends A
{
    C(int val)
    {
        super(val);     
    }

    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println("value in C = "+value);
    }
}

class D extends B
{
    D(int val)
    {
        super(val);     
    }

    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println("value in D = "+value);
    }
}

class E extends B
{
    E(int val)
    {
        super(val);     
    }

    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println("value in E = "+value);
    }
}

class F extends C
{
    F(int val)
    {
        super(val);     
    }

    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println("value in F = "+value);
    }
}

class G extends C
{
    G(int val)
    {
        super(val);     
    }

    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println("value in G = "+value);
    }
}

public class Polymorphism 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        A[] array = new A[7];

        //array of type A used to hold objects of all other classes which extend A           
        array[0] = new A(123);//holds object of type A
        array[1] = new B(321);//holds object of type B
        array[2] = new C(111);
        array[3] = new D(13);
        array[4] = new E(1248);
        array[5] = new F(165);
        array[6] = new G(191);//holds object of type G

        for( A a: array)
            a.print();//using reference of type A to invoke overridden functions from individual classes!! 
    }
}
```